# Unable to assign value to typescript dictionary

Tags: javascript, dictionary, typescript, typescript1.8

I created a typescript dictionary. When I assign value to it, I am getting the following error.

```
         TypeError: Cannot set property 'v1/items/someItemType/someItemId/EVENT/some
    DataTypeId' of undefined
          at MainClass.subscribe (G:\Projects\src\main\MainClass
    .js:9:3522)
          at Context.<anonymous> (G:\Projects\test\main\Wish.
    spec.js:45:18)
          at callFn (G:\Projects\node_modules\mocha\lib\runna
    ble.js:315:21)
          at Hook.Runnable.run (G:\Projects\node_modules\moch
    a\lib\runnable.js:308:7)
          at next (G:\Projects\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.
    js:298:10)
          at Immediate._onImmediate (G:\Projects\node_modules
    \mocha\lib\runner.js:320:5)
```

Below is how I declared the dictionary.

```
interface StringTopicToMyTopicMap {
  [topic: string]: MyTopic;
};
```

Below is the interface for MyTopic.

```
export interface MyTopic {
  dataTypeID: string;
  itemID: string;
  itemType: string;
  dataType: MyDataType;
  qos: number;
}
```

Then I tried assign value to this dictionary as shown below.

```
private subscriptionTopicsMap: StringTopicToMyTopicMap;

subscribe(myTopic: MyTopic) {
    if (_.isEmpty(myTopic)) {
      throw new MyError('myTopic cannot be empty');
    } else {
      let topic: string;
      topic = 'v1/items/' + myTopic.itemType + '/' + myTopic.itemID + '/'
        + myTopic.dataType + '/' + myTopic.dataTypeID;
      this.subscriptionTopicsMap[topic] = myTopic;
      this.client.subscribe(topic);
    }
  }
```

Error is thrown from the line,

```
this.subscriptionTopicsMap[topic] = myTopic;
```

I am new to typescript things. What am I doing wrong here? Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initialize your property when declared

```
//private subscriptionTopicsMap: StringTopicToMyTopicMap;
private subscriptionTopicsMap: StringTopicToMyTopicMap = {};
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually do this in an easier way, no need for the second interface.
Also as the answer before, you gonna need `={}` as below:

```
private subscriptionTopicsMap: { [id: string]: MyTopic; } = {};
this.subscriptionTopicsMap[topic] = myTopic;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not initialized your `subscriptionTopicsMap` dictionary,
Also you dont have any class which implements `StringTopicToMyTopicMap`, and may be instantiated

```
  class StringTopicToMyTopicMapClass implements StringTopicToMyTopicMap {
         [topic: string]: MyTopic;
  };

  private subscriptionTopicsMap: StringTopicToMyTopicMap = new StringTopicToMyTopicMapClass ();
```